# How to change $model->attributes value in controller - Yii

Tags: controller, yii, yii-components

UserMasterController Code:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['UserMaster'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['UserMaster'];
        $model->attributes['emailsent'] = 'N';

        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('admin'));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

the line which gives me an error is : `$model->attributes['emailsent'] = 'N';`

> **ERROR** : Indirect modification of overloaded property `UserMaster::$attributes` has no effect

How can I change the attribute value ? I just want to set it as `'Y'` or `'N'` as per the condition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$model->emailsent='N';`. Thats all

Comment: Any way to do this when I specifically want to bypass an existing setter?

Answer (score 5):

Just try this `$model->setAttribute($name,$value);`

Comment: This one is very useful if you want IN conditions etc. 1UP